# Is it possible to use Nodejs Crypto module functionality in Fabric Composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I would like to be able to use various functions from the nodejs crypto module in my Fabric Composer chaincode.  Is that possible?  I tried hashing a simple string within my chaincode but it didn't work - in Playground I received this error message: 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null.' and using CLI to local HLF the transaction never completed.  I tested my javascript hashing code separately and it works but not when I try to run it within chaincode.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you cannot use node modules in transaction processor functions- you're limited to base javascript. It's possible that nodejs support will come in the future, and making crypo APIs available in composer is another option being considered.

If you want to try something in the mean time, crypto-browserify might be worth investigating. I don't know if anyone has got that to work though, so please report back if you try it.